# How do I summarize and aggregate data in R where the variables to be summarised are in another variable?

Tags: r, aggregate, summarize

I have this data
[each facility is scored as one of red, yellow or green.  Want to summarize by % red scores for each aggregated area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXr0I.png)

and want to summarize it so that the green CEE scores are added and the red CEE scores are added and the yellow CEE scores are added across all facilities.  The red scores will then be shown as a percent of total scores for the aggregated group.  Each row can only been rated as green, yellow or red.  The final result should be something like
[where care_tr_gen = S2_02+S2_04+S2_05, care_tr_kp = S2_03_S3_01, supply chain = S3_02+S3_03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rubqp.png)

I haven't got this to work:
''''
sims_mer_combineda <-sims_mer_combined %>%
group_by(cee) %>%
summarise(care_tr_gen=S2_02+ S2_04+ S2_05)

```
''''
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please don't post code and data as pictures. Post them as copy/pasteable text! TO format a code block, put three backticks on a line before the block and after the block.

Comment: Also your code doesn't seem to match the data you show. Your data has column names like `cee_green`, `cee_red`, etc. Your code has columns like `S_02_03`, which isn't in any of your pictures. So this is quite confusing.